# My R^2 are negative for the cross validation

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am a beginner in Python. I am trying to do cross validation for my polynomial regressor. But I am getting negative values for R^2. Yet, my R^2 for the predicted model is 0.99! Any clue? Thank you.

Code:

```
X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Part's Surface Area (cm^2)","Layer Height (mm)","Infill Density (%)","Nozzle/Printing Temperature (C)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], data_set [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_normalized, y_for_normalized, test_size=0.25)


    lin_regressor = LinearRegression()
    
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)
    
    X_transform = poly.fit_transform(x_train)
    
    linear_regg=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform,y_train)  
    
    X_test_transform = poly.fit_transform(x_test)
    y_preds_polynomial_regressor = lin_regressor.predict(X_test_transform)
    
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    
    scores=(cross_val_score(lin_regressor, X_normalized, y_for_normalized, cv=5, scoring='r2'))
    scores
```

array([-22.34893294,   0.16442119,   0.16573873,  -8.01952229,
-51.74761889])

```
from sklearn import metrics
r_square = metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_preds_polynomial_regressor)
print('R-Square for the Polynomial Regression is:', r_square)
```

R-Square for the Polynomial Regression is: 0.9929200465728122